# $R^2$ is subspace of $R^3$ or not

Tags: linear-algebra

some author consider $R^2$ is subspace of $R^3$ but some author say $R^2$ is not a subspace of $R^3$.

so when they consider in which sense they consider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vector space $\mathbb R^2$ can be embedded into $\mathbb R^3$, that is, it is isomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. Actually there are infinitely many ways to embed $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R^3$, but they are actually equivalent (that is, for any two embedddings of $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^3$ there's an automorphism of $\mathbb R^3$ mapping those embeddings to each other).

Moreover there's a particularly simple embedding, which just maps the $k$-th basis vector of the standard basis of $\mathbb R^2$ to the $k$-th basis vector of the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$, resulting in the map
$$\pmatrix{x\\y}\mapsto\pmatrix{x\\y\\0}.$$

Now when talking about two vector spaces being the same, there are several philosophies. One is, you actually assume equality. In that sense, $\mathbb R^2$ is not a subspace of$\mathbb R^3$, as $\mathbb R^2$ consists of pairs of real numbers, and there are no pairs of real numbers in $\mathbb R^3$, only triples.

Another philosophy is to consider two vector spaces the same if they are the same *up to isomorphism,* that is, if they are isomorphic. And in that sense, $\mathbb R^2$ is clearly a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, as shown above.

A third philosophy is to consider two vector spaces the same is there exists a *canonical isomporphism* between them, that is, not only are they isomorphic, but you can single out a specific isomporphism which is particularly simple, particularly obvious, or has particularly nice properties. The map given above is such a canonical embedding of $\mathbb R^2$ in $\mathbb R^3$, thus also in this sense, $\mathbb R^2$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, an element $(x,y)$ of $\mathbb R^2$ is identified with $(x,y,0)\in\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Some authors may say no because $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$ only has two coordinates;   whereas in $\Bbb R^3$ every point (vector)  has three coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The only $\text{independent}$ subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ are

$(i)$ Lines passing through origin,

$(ii)$ planes passing through origin,

$(iii)$ $\mathbb{R}^3$,

$(iv)$  $\{0 \}$, the zero subspace

Now look at $(i)$, any two mutually perpendicular lines through origin generates the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Thus $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.